# Where to specify the path for Extension 'spartacussampledataaddon'

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I following the instruction at https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/installing-sap-commerce-cloud-2005/

Step 1: completed successful

Step 2: Build and initialize the new recipe

At this step I have got an error. Where I have to specify path for the extension?

```
# install.bat -r cx-for-spa
...

> Task :recipes:cx-for-spa:createStoreFrontExt
Buildfile: C:\cx2005\hybris\bin\platform\build.xml
[ysetplatformproperties] Error while evaluating file 'C:\cx2005\hybris\config\localextensions.xml'. Extension 'spartacussampledataaddon' doesn't specify a path and no scanned extension was matching the name. Please check file C:\cx2005\hybris\config\localextensions.xml.
[ysetplatformproperties] java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while evaluating file 'C:\cx2005\hybris\config\localextensions.xml'. Extension 'spartacussampledataaddon' doesn't specify a path and no scanned extension was matching the name. Please check file C:\cx2005\hybris\config\localextensions.xml.
```

Answer (score 2):

I met the same issue, and solved it:

Please check :

1,
hybris/bin/custom/spartacussampledata/extensioninfo.xml

```
<extension ... name="spartacussampledata">
```

2,
hybris/config/localextensions.xml

```
<extension name='spartacussampledata' />
```

Above extension name must be the **same**!

I guess you have **different** ones
one is **spartacussampledata** (extension)
and the other is spartacussampledata**addon** (addon)

Because Spartacus 3.0 and later use the new Spartacus sample data extension (not the addon).
For now Spartacus provides both for download. However, the sample data extension will be the only one updated in the future.
Both will work for older releases, the new extension contains updates to b2b sample data

Here is URL of spartacussampledata.zip version 3.0.0:
https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/releases/download/storefront-3.0.0/spartacussampledata.2005.zip

Answer (score 1):

You can store it at `/hybris/bin/custom`.

The modules and platform folder contain the standard modules that are shipped with the commerce release. The custom folder is supposed to contain your customer extensions.

The `spartacussampledataaddon` is a bit in between, as its shipped by product team, but outside the standard commerce release process.

Answer (score 1):

You probably downloaded "spartacussampledata.2005.zip", extracted it into your custom folder and renamed the folder to "spartacussampledataaddon".
What you need to do is not to rename the folder, but only remove the ".2005" so you will end up having "spartacussampledata", and then add this to your gradle config file or directly to your localextensions.

The "spartacussampledataaddon" name works for the 1905 version.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error and what turned out to be my problem was, that I used Windows CMD and clicked inside during setup so that it would freeze the command line output ( https://superuser.com/questions/459609/what-does-it-do-exactly-if-i-click-in-the-window-of-cmd). I don't know the exact details for this process, but if you are using Windows CMD, try to not  click into the CMD window during process. For me this most probably solved the issue, even if it sounds a bit strange.